# Will hiring managers and recruiters understand why I left so early?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, job-hopping

I’ve been working as a software developer for the past six months at the same company. However, I’ve recently had thoughts of leaving for a company that better fits my interests (culture and team work). The main problem that concerns me is I left my first job after six months to work for the company I’m at now and I don’t want to be seen as a job jumper.

I worked for a software consulting company right out of school but left after 6 months due to never being put at clients with work related to software engineering.

I am now working at another company as a Software Engineer. I am guaranteed a year of work but may or may not be brought on full time at the end of the year. Three months in I had some concerns about the work and culture but stuck it out to see if anything changed. Six months in, I am starting to realize I don’t really like the work. Almost all of the work I do is by myself with small help from a senior developer. She works on multiple projects so she doesn’t have much time to spend with me. I can spend entire days without talking to anyone (besides lunch and small informal chats here and there) and that’s normal. There is basically no culture as a team. We never go out for drinks or anything of that nature. We pretty much show up then go home.

Is this a valid reason for leaving? Will hiring managers understand my reasons for leaving so soon? I don’t want to be blacklisted as a job hopper but I also want to be happy and fulfilled when working in an industry I have great passion for.

Comment: "*Will hiring managers understand my reasons for leaving so soon*" Not unless you tell them. Or in the relatively [harsh words](http://www.businessinsider.com/mark-suster-never-hire-job-hoppers-never-they-make-terrible-employees-2010-4?IR=T) of Venture Capitalist Mark Suster: "*in a competitive job market you're less likely to get the chance to tell me your sob story*" More on that in my answers on related questions [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/59082/25739) and [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/109811/25739).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back to back 6 month jobs certainly would be a red flag for hiring companies.

However, it sounds like your current job is actually a 1 year contract with the potential to go full time after.  This gives you a strategy to deal with your situation.

I would wait a few months and start looking for a new job, listing the current job as a 1 year contract on your resume.  No one will question you trying to line up a new job near the end of a 1 year contract.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a valid reason for moving on.  Stick it out for at least a year.  Also, **your coworkers are not your friends**  Expecting them to get friendly with you, especially if you are on contract is a bit unrealistic.

Recruiters will not be sympathetic to your reasoning, and even though contract work excuses job jumping to some extent, it still raises concerns and you will be asked about it.  At that point, an answer like "there was no culture" is not going to earn you any points.

Work is not supposed to make you happy or fulfilled, but the paycheck justifies it.  If you were to interview with me and gave me those reasons for leaving, I'd have serious doubts about hiring you.

Now, after a year, you could move on and say that it wasn't a good fit because you do better in a collaborative environment, and the one you were leaving was one where everyone worked in isolation.  **THAT** would be perfectly acceptable.

But leaving two jobs after six months?  No, I wouldn't expect to be well received.  Stick it out for a year, then look, or start looking at about 11 months.

THAT you can justify with "well, my contract is almost up, so I'm looking again"  Or "I'm looking for permanent employment."  But right now, it's too soon to have too short jobs in succession.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you are on the contract you cannot be seen as Job-Jumper

Contract implies term and, sadly, it is often a short-term

You should describe both of you current and previous engagements as term contracts.
And as great answer regarding job search - "looking for a full time position"

No one wants to be hanging in mid air, hoping for contract renewal